# SQL in runnable jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, jar

I know this probably something simple but i can't figure it out...

I'm trying to convert one of my programs to a runnable jar and it does some SQL  with JDBC. When i export the project i choose to "extract all required libraries into runnable jar", i have the JDBC on my build path.

Here's the part of my code i'm getting hung up on...

```
String serverURL = ****
String user = ****
String pass = ****
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(serverURL, user, pass);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    //print stacktrack to a dialogbox
}
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM myDB");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    //print stacktrack to a dialogbox
}
```

So the program runs fine in Eclipse but when i run it as a runnable jar the execution seems to halt at the executeQuery line. I've done some JDialogs to see where the problem might be it looks like conn is set up (or at least it isn't null). Since conn isn't null i assume that means the JDBC is working correctly. The weird thing iis there are no exceptions as far as i can tell, the program just stops at the executeQuery line. Any ideas why this might be?

Edit: stack trace before the problem occurs

```
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:64)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(WToolkit.java:306)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(AWTAutoShutdown.java:295)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.Thread.dumpThreads(Native Method)
java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1607)
HandMapper.loadRecorded(HandMapper.java:161)
HandMapper.load(HandMapper.java:88)
HandMapper.main(HandMapper.java:255)
sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer._dispose(Native Method)
sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.disposeImpl(WComponentPeer.java:638)
sun.awt.windows.WWindowPeer.disposeImpl(WWindowPeer.java:117)
sun.awt.windows.WObjectPeer.dispose(WObjectPeer.java:88)
java.awt.Component.removeNotify(Component.java:7042)
java.awt.Container.removeNotify(Container.java:2820)
java.awt.Window.removeNotify(Window.java:782)
java.awt.Frame.removeNotify(Frame.java:1041)
java.awt.Window$1DisposeAction.run(Window.java:1190)
java.awt.Window.doDispose(Window.java:1206)
java.awt.Window.dispose(Window.java:1147)
javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.dispose(SwingUtilities.java:1814)
javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.windowClosed(SwingUtilities.java:1792)
java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowClosed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:359)
java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2057)
javax.swing.JDialog.processWindowEvent(JDialog.java:683)
java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2013)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:148)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Print out ALL stack traces. Always. There is important information.

Comment: Can you please add the program's stacktrace?

Comment: @yorodm I added the complete stack trace right before the problem occurs. Not sure if this what you wanted?

Comment: It seems that something is failing in your connection, are you running the `jar` file in the same machine as  your IDE? Did you check your firewall settings?

Comment: The jar is local and yes i'm running them on the same machine (same wirewall settings). I did a isValid() on my connection which returns true.

Comment: btw apparently it was an out of memory error. eclipse was using a different heap size than the system jvm. so that's why it ran fine in eclipse, didn't run outside of eclipse, and didn't show any errors in the try catch

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Maven to package your dependencies and your application

A good site visit https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/

an example:

```
<project>
[...]
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <archive>
                  <manifest>
                      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                      <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
              </archive>
              <descriptorRefs>
                  <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>single</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
  [...]
  </plugins>
  [...]
 </build>
</project>
```